# BSOD in Windows 7 on Virtualbox when running RDP

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, rdp, bsod

I've been having a lot of trouble over the past couple of days. I set up a Win7 work environment in Virtualbox and everything has been running smoothly until I tried to use Remote Desktop. I can log in to the remote machine normally and everything works for a while but then all of a sudden, my guest Win7 machine restarts due to a BSOD. I thought it might be a memory or space issue so I upped the VM's RAM to 4GB (Host system is 8GB) and the HDD to 45 GB. I also enabled I/O APIC and PAE/NX which improved performance on the guest machine but running RDP for a few minutes still triggers a BSOD. I also increased video memory from 128MB to 256MB. I don't know what else to do and I don't know how to analyze dump files. I was able to see that the last 4 error check strings were the following:

- KERNEL_MODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED
- IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL
- MEMORY_MANAGEMENT
- KERNEL_MODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED

I'm attaching the last 4 minidumps in here: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-hWzWXaH29hZXVVbjVmTkV4Vkk/edit?usp=sharing

Any help would be immensely helpful. Thank you all in advance.

Cheers,
Luis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that virtualization was disabled on the host machine's BIOS which prevented me from accessing the Acceleration tab in the VM's settings. Once I changed the host machine's BIOS settings to enable virtualization, I was able to enable Hardware virtualization in the VirtualBox settings and the problem went away. I also added extra disk space for good measure.